# end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Tags: php, json

Alright so i'm fairly new to PHP, JSON and the like. I got an assignment to input HTML5 form into a JSON database, and to recall that info aswell.

```
<?php
$f_name     = $_POST['f_name'];
$l_name     = $_POST['l_name'];
$u_email    = $_POST['u_email'];
$u_adress   = $_POST['u_adress'];
$u_postcode = $_POST['u_postcode'];
$u_place    = $_POST['u_place'];
$u_birth    = $_POST['u_birth'];

$file = file_get_contents("data.json");
$data = json_decode('data.json', true);

$last_item    = end($data);
$last_item_id = $last_item['id'];



$data[] = array(

    'f_name'=>$f_name,
    'l_name'=>$l_name,
    'u_email'=>$u_email,
    'u_adress' =>$u_adress,
    'u_postcode' =>$u_postcode,
    'u_place'=>$u_place,
    'u_birth'=>$u_birth,
    'id' =>++$last_item_id
    );


file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($data));
?>
```

and this is the output

```
[{"f_name":"Jack","l_name":"Smith","u_email":"jacksmith@hotmail.com","u_adress":"Something 1","u_postcode":"1111 AA","u_place":"SomeCity","u_birth":"jjjj-mm-dd","id":1}]
```

so the ID should be the auto increment but when i try that i get this error:

```
end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

which refers to this part

```
 $last_item    = end($data);
 $last_item_id = $last_item['id'];
```

Comment: typo `json_decode($file, true);`

Comment: check if `$data` is an array using `is_array($data)`

Comment: Apparently `json_decode()` fails and returns `false`.

Comment: Try with `$data = json_decode($file, true);`

Comment: Yeah @Mike...when I was reading the answer, and posting the comment, the other comments where not reflected...

Comment: Change `$data = json_decode('data.json', true);` to `$data = json_decode($file, true);`

Comment: You should use a database for this. This can - theoretically - get you duplicate id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
$data = json_decode('data.json', true);
```

with:

```
$data = json_decode($file, true);
```

and there is no need to extract id again. Delete:

```
$last_item_id = $last_item['id'];
```

use last_item after:

```
$data = array(

    'f_name'=>$f_name,
    'l_name'=>$l_name,
    'u_email'=>$u_email,
    'u_adress' =>$u_adress,
    'u_postcode' =>$u_postcode,
    'u_place'=>$u_place,
    'u_birth'=>$u_birth,
    'id' =>++$last_item
    );
```

Please note that you are not saving the data in correct json 1D array you actually make it 2D if you use `$data[] = array(....)` 
If you want to keep it then replace:

```
$last_item = end($data);
```

with:

```
$last_item = end($data[0]);
```

Long story short, working codes can be either:

```
$data = json_decode($file, true);
$last_item = end($data[0]);
 $data[] = array(

        'f_name'=>$f_name,
        'l_name'=>$l_name,
        'u_email'=>$u_email,
        'u_adress' =>$u_adress,
        'u_postcode' =>$u_postcode,
        'u_place'=>$u_place,
        'u_birth'=>$u_birth,
        'id' =>++$last_item
        );
```

OR

```
$data = json_decode($file, true);
$last_item = end($data);
 $data = array(

        'f_name'=>$f_name,
        'l_name'=>$l_name,
        'u_email'=>$u_email,
        'u_adress' =>$u_adress,
        'u_postcode' =>$u_postcode,
        'u_place'=>$u_place,
        'u_birth'=>$u_birth,
        'id' =>++$last_item
        );
```

depends how you want.
*I hope it helps*

Comment: The last part is wrong. Look at the data-structure of the json, it is an array of objects.

Comment: jeroen has made a good point. I have edited my answer. You should use $data not $data[] to save your finallize data in a file. Because currently your are not saving a json 1D array in file, you are saving json 2D array. If you want to keep saving as a 2D array then ypu need to use : $last_item    = end($data[0]); while extracting id.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses! Although the error itself is fixed now i still have a problem extracting the ID and incrementing it. As it stands now it just shows an empty id.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the last value of the array given that this is a json data, you have to first use json_decode.

```
$data = '[{"f_name":"Jack","l_name":"Smith","u_email":"jacksmith@hotmail.com","u_adress":"Something 1","u_postcode":"1111 AA","u_place":"SomeCity","u_birth":"jjjj-mm-dd","id":"1"}]';
```

Since when you decode it, it is still under an array but just one index, get that index and try this:

```
$new_data = json_decode($data, true);
$last_item_id = end($new_data);
$id = $last_item_id = $last_item_id["id"];

$data = array(
'f_name'=>$f_name,
'l_name'=>$l_name,
'u_email'=>$u_email,
'u_adress' =>$u_adress,
'u_postcode' =>$u_postcode,
'u_place'=>$u_place,
'u_birth'=>$u_birth,
'id' => $id + 1
);
```

Comment: Based on the code, I would think the OP would want the ID of the last item in the json file, not the first one.

Comment: Edited my answer sir, it seems its not just the problem of the OP, the end() is throwing an error.

Comment: `$new_data[0]` gets the first element, not the last.

Comment: If the data given as I provided, it should not be the first element.

Comment: The data will probably **not** be as provided. The only reason this would work with the data provided is because there is only one element in the array, so the first is the same as the last.

Comment: I see! Sorry. I'll edit my answer.